# AWS ElasticBeanstalk and PM2 integration

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, pm2

I am trying to integrate pm2 so that it can restart the server if any case it stopped.

I followed the pm2 documentation guidelines from this website: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/tutorials/use-pm2-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk

However, it is running on no-daemon mode and I ssh to the instance then manually started the pm2 as displayed on the screenshot below.
And the status is errored when I am performing pm2 list.

Please help and thanks in advance.
[Screenshot log 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0QTw.png)

Comment: Where's the screenshot?

Comment: @Techuila Sorry for that. I will edit the post since I don't have much reputation,  it didn't allow me to show the screenshot directly.

Comment: Execute `pm2 logs 0`. What's the error message? or if you can include the findings on your post.

Comment: @Techuila There is no error message on this log. I have added the screenshot as log 0 link. The only error it is displaying is the PMW is not UP TO Date.